# Use different namespaces in a single project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, namespaces, solution

I have two projects in a single solution in VS 2010. The project's name are WpfApplication2 and WpfApplication1. I want to use in the WpfApplication2 the namespace, classes and others content in WpfApplication1 for example like in this case [image]

but return me always an error when i write `using WpfApplication1.Db;` error. I found on the net that i should add references. I've tried [image]

but doesn't work. Where i wrong ?

Comment: That's the project dependencies window, not the "Add Reference" window

Comment: Right click that *References* folder in WpfApplication2, and click *Add Reference...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a reference to the other project.

- Right click on "References" in your WpfApplication2 project
- Choose "Solution" -> "Projects"
- Select the WpfApplication1 project and click Add/Ok

Then you should have a reference to it and be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You should [separate your tiers](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/05/01/pcuix_ui-architecture.aspx): judging from what little information you give it seems you have DB methods in one WPF project you want to use in another WPF project.

If possible, make sure your project only does one thing (e.g. handle DB calls, or business logic, or UI). Basically, apply [n-tier architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658117.aspx).